# Hibernate @ManyToOne always loads entity with referencedColumnName

Tags: hibernate

I've got a class CurrentValue with the following Hibernate mapping. It maps an entity by a referencedColumnName:

```
@Table(name = "CURRENTVALUE")
public class CurrentValue {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITYVALUEID", referencedColumnName = "COMPOSITEVALUED")
  private EntityValue entityValue;
  ...
}
```

When I load the entity CurrentValue by a HQL-query, it always loads the entity EntityValue. In the class TwoPhaseLoad the method doInitializeEntity is fired with this object in de hydratedState-array. I can't seem to figure out why it does this, eventhough it is LAZY fetched. Even if I JOIN FETCH it in the HQL query, it still performs a SELECT statement. Is this intended and can't I do anything about it?

Using Hibernate 5.2.17.Final.